# Android BluetoothSocket.connect() Returns, But The Opposite Accept() Call Doesn't

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm trying to get the Android Bluetooth APIs working, and I'm running into a strange problem. I have one device (Samsung Nexus S) as the client, calling socket.connect(), and the other device (also Samsung Nexus S) calling serverSocket.accept() (after doing device discovery, creating the sockets using createInsecureRfcommSocketToServiceRecord and listenInsecure...).

I put debug statements after connect(), and I can see that connect() is returning successfully (because it would throw an exception if it weren't). However, the accept() call on the other end just blocks, and eventually times out.

Any ideas what could cause this? As far as I can tell, the socket is connecting, but my process isn't being informed.

UPDATE:

The manifestation of the bug was a bit mysterious, but I'm pretty sure that I was mishandling threading, and that was somehow preventing the thread running accept() from unblocking.